# Select list scroll to a specific option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box with years. First option is empty. When I click on select list I want scrollbar to scroll automaticaly down . I've tried with scrollTop but it's working only in FireFox.

Ex:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="1911">1911</option>
<option value="1912">1912</option>
<option value="1913">1913</option>
<option value="1914">1914</option>
<option value="1915">1915</option>
<option value="1916">1916</option>
<option value="1917">1917</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
...

</select>
```

Comment: Why not just reverse the order of the dates? :)

Comment: A little more explanation, please? Do you want the dropdown to scroll to the bottom of the list? If so, why not invert the order so the last one is on the top?

Comment: I just want to scroll down the vertical scrollbar with 400px for example without selecting any option because I want the user to see most important options from select list before he selects an option

Answer (score 2):

Select click/focus is a bit more complicated, actually. This is what you want:

```
$('#mySelect').focus(function(){

    if($(this).data('focused') !==  true)
    {
        $(this).data('focused',true);  
        $(this).children(':last-child').prop('selected',true);
    }

});

$('#mySelect').blur(function(){
    $(this).data('focused',false); 
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/zuJrK/

Comment: Best solution thus far in my opinion.

Comment: I just want to scroll down the vertical scrollbar with 400px for example without selecting any option because I want the user to see most important options from select list before he selects an option

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code I hope it helps

```
$("#mySelect").click(function(){
   $(this).find("option").eq(someMiddleNumber).focus().blur();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that select the 1922'd option in the select?

Comment: @Phil - I interpreted your question wrong but now I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: I just want to scroll down the vertical scrollbar with 400px for example without selecting any option because I want the user to see most important options from select list before he selects an option

Comment: In that case select any middle option and set the focus to that it will scroll to that option but wont select it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to remove the style "overflow-y:auto;" from css, that will keep the selected item scroll into the view (when you use arrow keys to change the selection).

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement to AlienWebguy's answer:

You can make sure the default value will stay selected in case user does not make any changes by adding the settimeout section below:

```
if($(this).data('focused') !==  true)
{
    $(this).data('focused',true);  
    $(this).children(':last-child').prop('selected',true);
    // dirty workaround
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: Can't comment yet :) Had to post as an additional answer since I have been struggling with it for few hours.

Answer (score -1):

ShankarSangoli was close but I think you want:

```
$("#mySelect").click(function(){
   $(this).find("option:last").attr("selected","selected");
});
```

Comment: I just want to scroll down the vertical scrollbar with 400px for example without selecting any option because I want the user to see most important options from select list before he selects an option

Comment: I don't think there is a way to move that scrollbar without besides selecting an option. You could put special class on the option where the important options start and do: $(this).find(".specialclass").attr("selected","selected");