# How to open bootstrap select list selection in the middle value option

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to default the Bootstrap dropdowns so that they open in the middle of the value options?

When i Click on Select Menu its open from top value by default like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkHg9.jpg)

[image]

I’d like it to open on the most popular options (5’0’’ to 6’2’’), like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxA8z.jpg)

[image]

Please Can Any One Help me on this Problem :)

Comment: Please put your code here

Comment: just select your 5'0" option as selected

Comment: There is no native way how to "scroll" to middle of the the dropdown without making any item as selected. See comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568465/open-select-dropdown-to-middle-values#answer-9569875

Answer (score 0):

One of the most straight-forward options would simply be to set your preferred value, such as `5'0"` as the selected option :

```
<select>
    <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
    <option>4'10</option>
    <option>4'11</option>
    <option selected>5'0</option>
    <option>5'1</option>
    <option>5'2</option>
    <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
</select>
```

Otherwise, you could use some type of implementation that would attempt to select the "middle" element within your list via the [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) function :

```
// Attempt to resolve the middle element of your list
$('select option:eq(' + $('#select option').length / 2 + ')').prop('selected',true);
// Instantiate your select picker
$('select').selectpicker();
```

Both of [these examples can be seen here](http://jsbin.com/howaho/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below:

[image]

If you want to make it a bit easier for the user, you might consider taking advantage of some of the features offered by the same plugin like [live search](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search) to allow the user to begin typing to access their selection.